# How to make composition where both entities have 'has' a relation with each other

Tags: c#, oop

Taking a simple example:
Customer can place order on ecommerce website.

Now, I can infer two composition ('has a' relationship) from this statement.

1. Order has a customer.
2. Customer has one or multiple orders.

How should i create class for this. What all factors should i keep in mind while designing these two classes. Below are possibilities i have found till now.

1. Order class with customerId.
2. Order class with Customer object.
3. Customer class with no order history. (Since i can still find information about customer order from order table)
4. Customer class with List of OrderId.
5. Customer class with List of Order objects.

How do i decide which is best for a situation?

Comment: That really depends on your use case. What do you want to do with a customer? What do you want to do with an order? How will you consume this data? Will you be querying by customer id or by order id, or maybe by both? This isn't enough and a generally broad question.

Comment: I want it for typical e commerce website. They do have customer's order history which they display on customer's profile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first possibility is the simple one which seems enough for your case! An order will have the customer id as a foreign key.

Comment: Yes. Thats what i have done but wondering what would happen when system would have billions of order. Wouldn't it be too slow to retrieve customer order history?

Comment: I can't imagine any better approach, this is the most optimal, when the system has as big number of orders as you say, you may refer to other techniques such as indexing and caching.